# Intellij-Share project on Github

Tags: java, maven, github, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a repository from a Spring,Maven project from Intellij but when I try to "Share" it on Github this happens.

http://prnt.sc/deaqyw

It does not push the src folder.

http://prntscr.com/dearlg

I also have the .idea folder at ignored files in Version Control in Intellij.

In Version Control tab at the Directory tab I have the src folder and the project's entire folder.

Sorry for the links I cannot post photos.

Comment: don't waste time, just share the project from the command line

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Project
VCS > Import into Version Control > Share Project on GitHub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to github repository 
 Click on settings | scroll down | delete repository
 Open your project in IntelliJ and navigate to following path:

Click on VCS | Import int Version Control | Share Poject on GitHub

This will open a window for new repository name and initial share comment.
Provide detail and press 'ok'. You are done.

Or

Go to terminal window of IntelliJ and follow these command line steps in the given sequence:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin 'your repository url' 
git remote -v    
git push origin master
```